# setting control property in cs file

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to set the control binding property "updatesource=Explicit" in cs file (dynamically) not in UI end. Please help me how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

it works :)

```
this.GetBindingExpression(SomeProperty).ParentBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating the binding in code manually?  If so you can just set it like any other property:

```
var binding = new Binding("BindingPath")
{
    Source = myDataObject,
    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit
}    
textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
```

[More information here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and it works. :-) The code remains the same as Gimalay's.

```
BindingExpression bindingExpr = this.textBox1.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
bindingExpr.ParentBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit;
```